# New-ADuser - Argument OtherAttributes

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I am working on a New-ADuser script for the company I work in.
I have set the below hashtable in which the value 'serialnumber' is to be set or not depending on the new user's requirements.

```
$hashtable = @{

Name = $User.Surname + " " + $User.Givenname
Surname = $User.Surname
Givenname = $User.Givenname
Samaccountname = $User.Samaccountname
Emailaddress = $User.Emailaddress
Accountpassword = $User.password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Path = $User.Path
UserPrincipalName = $User.Samaccountname + "@anything.com"
OtherAttributes = @{serialNumber =$User.serialnumber}

}
```

I am using a CSV file to get all the information but in the event that field 'serialnumber' is not filled in then I cannot get my script to work.
It errors something like 'the argument is Null or empty'.

Is there any way to bypass this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$serialNum = ""
$Props = @{
    Name = "testmay14_2"
    Surname = "may14_2"
    GivenName = "test"
    SamaccountName = "testmay14_2" 
    EmailAddress = "testmay14_2@domain.com"
    Accountpassword = "Password!1" |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    UserPrincipalName = "testmay14_2@domain.com"
    OtherAttributes = if(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($serialNum))){@{serialNumber = $serialNum}}else {@{serialNumber = 'NA'}}
}
New-ADUser @Props
```

May be you don't touch SerialNumber attribute at all in the 'else' block and use some other attribute which is not used.. just a thought

```
OtherAttributes = if(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($serialNum))){@{serialNumber = $serialNum}}else {@{Title="TheOneWithoutSerialNumber"}}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've just tried but in the 'else' case I would like the value to remain clear. It seems that OtherAttributes argument does not like it to be stuffed with 'empty' value. I think I will have to go with a bunch of if statements along with Set-ADuser.

Comment: Maybe you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I thought it was not 'clean' at first sight but luckily I have one attribute to set whether the new user has a serial number or not. Then it goes perfectly! Thank you mon ami ! ;)